# How to calculate max and min values from a comma-separated string column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table in Power BI that contains a column with comma-separated values, like this(Spalte 2 actually has 10000 points, i have shown 10 points):

| Spalte 1 | Spalte 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23,45,66,55,11,333,44,55,66,77 |
| 2 | 233,45,66,55,11,333,44,55,66,77 |
| 3 | 23,45,66,55,11,333,44,55,66,773 |
| ... | ... |

I want to add two new columns to the table that show the maximum and minimum values of each row, based on the values in the "Spalte 2" column. For example:

| Spalte 1 | Spalte 2 | Max Value | Min Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23,45,66,55,11,333,44,55,66,77 | 333 | 11 |
| 2 | 233,45,66,55,11,333,44,55,66,77 | 333 | 11 |
| 3 | 23,45,66,55,11,333,44,55,66,773 | 773 | 11 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried using the "SPLIT" function, but it did not work. Can someone suggest a DAX formula that can achieve this? Thank you.

```
Max Value = MAX(VALUE(SPLIT([Spalte 2],",")))
Min Value = MIN(VALUE(SPLIT([Spalte 2],",")))
```

Comment: You should do this in Power Query, not in DAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative in PQ if you want to test performance.

```
List.Max( List.Transform (Text.Split([Spalte 2], ","), each Number.From(_)))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How was the performance?

Comment: To accomplish this task, it's necessary to import the table as it cannot be in direct query mode. In my case, performing calculations for each column of the table takes approximately 15 minutes, but since I have only a few columns, it's still feasible. Despite the alternative method you suggested in a previous response, I prefer using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do this in DAX using PATH() functions but that would be a terrible use of DAX and not the right approach. Your data is in the wrong shape and needs to be reshaped in Power Query before doing analysis in DAX.

Do the following in Power Query:

Starting table:

[image]

Split column by delimiter and split to rows:

[image]

[image]

You now have 2 choices. You can either group by in Power Query:

[image]

[image]

Or leave it ungrouped, load to your model and write 2 measures as follows:

```
Max Measure = MAX('Table'[Spalte 2]) 
Min Measure = MIN('Table'[Spalte 2])
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify, the example table I provided earlier only showed 10 values per row, but the actual table I am working with has 10000 values per row, and the total row count is around a million. Using the method you suggested might cause my system to freeze or hang. Therefore, I am looking for an alternative solution that can quickly scan over the array and extract the maximum and minimum values without overloading the system.

Comment: Perhaps even further upstream is more efficient. What type of data source are you fetching from? I feel like doing this downstream is just the wrong end of things completely!